# Java MongoDB Exception: can't authenticate twice on the same database

Tags: java, mongodb, authentication

I've got a problem with MongoDB User Authentication using the Java driver 2.11.1. I added some admin-users (dbAdmins, userAdmins etc.) to the admin database.

As suggested by the MongoDB tutorial, I use only one instance of the MongoClient object: it's implemented as singleton because the MongoClient object is like an connection pool.

If an admin wants to have access to the database, he will make up a new connection to the database with the global MongoClient instance (get one connection from the pool) and call the authentication method of the driver: an example:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("ip", "port");

DB adminDB = mongoClient.getDB("admin");

boolean isAuth = adminDB.authenticate("Admin", "Admin1234".toCharArray());


DB anotherAdminDB = mongoClient.getDB("admin");

boolean isAuth2 = anotherAdminDB.authenticate("UserAdmin", "UserAdmin1234".toCharArray());
```

If I do so, I will get the exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: can't authenticate twice on the same
>   database

But each admin user has to authenticate with it's own credentials. Does anyone had this problem already? How could you solve that problem?

If I create a new MongoClient per admin, then there is no exception thrown and all is correct. But then I can't use the connection pooling of Mongo.

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: You can create 2 MongoClient, which will work, and there will be two connection pooling. Whats the harm ?

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned (one comment downwards) it's a distributed RMI application with many users. If I create one MongoClient per user session, then I have to handle all the connection stuff like closing etc. what the connection pool would do for me. Another point is the possibility of performance loss. But at that point I really don't understand why MongoDB allows to create different users when there's a limitation that only one concurrently authentication per database is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that limitation is by design. Maybe mongodb authentication is more appropriate in the context of application <-> database, not from user <-> application. If you need to authenticate user access to your application, better to implement it your own (eg: using Java EE / Spring Security)

Comment: Yes, that could be a design limitation. I already implemented an authentication method with JAAS into my RMI project. But I want to have an access control for the documents stored in the MongoDB instance. So that some "standard" users could only read the documents and some admins could insert new documents, update documents etc. For that I have to create users and authenticate with those credentials. It is only possible to create a MongoClient instance per User to do so or do you have any other suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: In that case you need to implement both authentication and authorization in your application -- rather than relying on MongoDB to do it. I know this is different concept to typical RDBMS like Oracle. This is because -- as you mentioned -- if you use one MongoClient instance per user session, you might lose efficiency on your application